# Spark history logs decompress manually

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, lz4

I have some problems with spark history server and therefore tried to uncompress `lz4` logs manually. I installed `liblz4-tool` and downloaded application log `application_1510049252849_0303.lz4`. But when uncompressing it with `lz4 ~/application_1510049252849_0303.lz4` I got the following error:

```
Error 44 : Unrecognized header : file cannot be decoded
```

And this I have for every spark history `lz4` files. What is the solution? Is there a way to open it manually?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error yesterday while trying to decompress the lz4 event logs. Apparently there seems to be some incompatibilities between hadoop lz4 codec and other lz4 codecs: see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-12990.

For what it's worth, spark history server can read compressed event logs in lz4, so you don't need to decompress them manually. Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually yes, I ended up in writing a simple app using Spark api to decompress it.

Answer (score 0):

lz4 no need to decompress while placing into spark history server. Just you can place your event logs into event log directory. It will automatically pick that application and show it in the Spark History Server UI.